# Loyalty API's "Get Member Details" returns unsuccessful response with no explanation whenever Contact is involved

Tags: apex, rest-api, contact, loyalty-management

TL;DR is title basically.

What I'm trying to do is simply:

1. Create an "Update Member Details" loyalty process from template. Activate it without any modification. *Note: It includes updates for both member and its contact.*
2. Using this OOTB [Update Member Details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.loyalty.meta/loyalty/connect_resources_update_member_details.htm) Loyalty API endpoint, I attempt to update member's basic fields such as enrollment date and email, providing membership number.
3. I get below unsuccessful response.

   {
   "message": null,
   "outputParameters": {},
   "simulationDetails": {},
   "status": false
   }

Later that I was able to isolate the issue that it was caused by Contact part of this API. After modifying Loyalty Process to only update Member record, then it worked.

So I starting chasing how to fix the problem in Contact part of API. I tried below steps to pinpoint what the issue was in Contact update, after modifying Loyalty Process to only include Contact update:

1. Disabled the Account apex trigger (we use person accounts)
2. Disabled two Processes I saw firing in the debug log
3. Did a trivial update (meaning I mapped no fields in request)

In the debug log I see no exception messages, also no VALIDATION_FAIL rows. Still does not work, I get the same response. My guess is that something happens in the "loyaltyprocessengine" process that goes south.

I'm aware that there is a simple and basic workaround such as for Contacts, instead of this, just do a REST update() call to member's contact. But still I would like to stick to OOTB APIs of Loyalty tool.